# Pdf about conic optimization

Tags: optimization, reference-request, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

Because of COVID I can't go in library to do some research, so I ask you any reference to books dealing with conic optimization, conic duality and Fenchel's duality. I state that I don't know anything about these arguments, so I have to find a *pdf* not too complicated.

Could you please provide me any links? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see Lectures on modern convex optimization by Ben-Tal and Nemirovski.?

Answer (score 1):

The topics that you've mentioned are covered in the textbook by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe:

[https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/)

Lecture notes by Aharon Ben-Tal and Arkadi Nemirovsky are also available online:

[https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/)

These are both posted with the permission of the publisher.